# Not showing selected item from listview in the next listview(Sub Menu)

Tags: android, json, listview

i m new to android..i have made listview where data is coming from server in listview,..i want to make another listview in next page where subcategory will come from main category .for that i need to get selected item id for intent.
here is my code it shows empty toast when i run the app.

```
public class TypeMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String TAG = TypeMenu.class.getSimpleName();
    String bid;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView lv;
    private static final String TAG_BID = "bid";

        // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "......com/brtemp/index.php";
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_type_menu);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        contactList = new ArrayList<>();

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        new GetContacts().execute();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(TypeMenu.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading book details.");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
                // getting values from selected ListItem

                TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);

                //where list_content is the id of TextView in listview_item.xml

                String text = textView.getText().toString();
                System.out.println("Choosen item= : " + text);

                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SubMenu.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_BID ,text);
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Toast" +  bid,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

     /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     */
    private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(TypeMenu.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Toast",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

            Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArry = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArry.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject c = jsonArry.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = c.getString("id");
                        String type = c.getString("type");
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                        contact.put("id", id);
                        contact.put("type", type);
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
                } catch (final JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });
               }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                           "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    TypeMenu.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "type"},
                    new int[]{
                    R.id.type});

            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

     }
}
```

This is my list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Product id (pid) - will be DDEN - used to pass to other activity -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside `onItemClick`,

```
HashMap<String, String> selected = contactList.get(position);
String id = new ArrayList<>(selected.keySet()).get(0);
String type = selected.get(id);

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "id = " + id + " type = " + type, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: on get(0)i got error ..it shows cannot resolve method get(int)

Comment: i have put id and type in listview...where i m just showing type in listview n hiding id..but when i go to next page tht selected id should b intent....

Comment: after takin ur code it is showing selected type but not id in toast...halfway it was rite..needed exact ans

Comment: Which `Toast` are you talking about? Can I assume you are passing `keyId` to `SubMenu.class`?

Comment: yes u r rite..in toast i just checking whether the selected item is id or type...eg..my id is 1 and type is pizza

Comment: so i want to pass the id to submenu...coz in database the data will come according to selected id  in subMenu

Comment: i have made a database where according to selected id the submenu will show subitem in app

Comment: What is the issue now?

Comment: its nt showing the id..like it should show 1 (id)instead of "pizza"(type)